# how can be prove that $\max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

how can be prove that $\max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

though the big O case is simple since $\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq f(n)+g(n)$

edit : where $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are asymptotically nonnegative functions.

Comment: It is false by the common mathematical definition: $f(n) = n, g(n) = -n$. What definition of BigOh are you using? (I know you have tagged it algorithms, so I believe I can guess, but just making sure...)

Comment: @Jonas Yes.they are non negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint...: $2 + 100 \le 100 + 100$

For the sake of completeness:

> Use the fact that: $\max(f,g) \le f + g \le  2\max(f,g)$ when $f,g$ are non-negative

Comment: i don't know whatever the constant n0 we choose , the $f(n0)+g(n0) < = max(f(n0),g(n0))$ is not going to hold, since they are non negative.

Comment: @Bunny: How is that relevant to the hint above?

Comment: only if the above condition holds for some constant n0 then we can prove the $\omega$ case i.e the lower bound.

Comment: @Bunny: Huh? I really suggest you put some thought into it. What I wrote is just a hint. Even a little more, and I have given you the solution.

Comment: Okay got it , i had actually not noticed that there can be two different constant for lower bound and the upper bound respectively , Thanks,that you didn't give away the whole solution , the hint made this lazy fella work a little , thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bunny: Glad it helped. If the constant is same for lower and upper bound, then they both have to be equal! So you can rule that out :-)