# Prove that $\max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can be prove that $\max(f(n),g(n)) = \theta(f(n)+g(n))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15129/how-can-be-prove-that-maxfn-gn-thetafngn)

How to prove $max(f(n),g(n)) = Θ(f(n)+g(n))$?

Comment: Is $\Theta(f(x))$ the same as $O(f(x))$ of "big-O" fame?

Comment: @robjohn: $f = \Theta(g)$ if _both_ $f = O(g)$ and $g = O(f)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h=\max(f,g)$. Then $f+g\le 2h$ and so $f+g=O(h)$. If $f$ and $g$ are positive, then $h \le f+g$ and so $h=O(f+g)$.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you.