# Formally prove that $\Theta(\max(f,g)) = \Theta(f+g)$

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

I am having a hard time proving that $\Theta(\max(f,g)) = \Theta(f+g) $

where

$(f+g)(n) = f(n) + g(n) $

and

$(\max{f,g})(n) = \max(f(n), g(n))$

I know that $\Theta$ is the combination of the upper and lower bounds, but I can't seem to prove this. It's hard for me to see how $\Theta$ of the max of two functions can be equivalent to $\Theta$ of the two functions added together.  Any guidance would be appreciated. Let me know if I can provide more info.

[This question is similar, but didn't quite help.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62917/prove-that-maxfn-gn-thetafngn)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f,g \geq 0$, then $\frac{1}{2}(f+g) \leq \max(f,g) \leq (f+g)$. Rearranging gives $ \max(f,g) \leq (f+g) \leq  2 \max(f,g)$.

It follows that $\Theta(f+g) = \Theta(\max(f,g))$.

**Addendum**: When we write $a \in \Theta(b)$, it means that there exists $\underline{k}, \overline{k} >0$, and $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $\underline{k} b(n) \leq a(n) \leq \overline{k} b(n)$. Note that if $a \in \Theta(b)$, then $\frac{1}{\overline{k}} a(n) \leq b(n) \leq \frac{1}{\underline{k}} a(n)$, and so $b \in \Theta(a)$, hence it is an equivalence relation.

The above shows that if we choose $\underline{k} = \frac{1}{2}$, $\overline{k} = 1, N=1$, then $\underline{k}(f(n)+g(n)) \leq \max(f(n),g(n)) \leq \overline{k}(f(n)+g(n))$, and hence $n \mapsto \max(f(n),g(n)) \in \Theta(n \mapsto f(n)+g(n))$, or, more colloquially, 
$\max(f,g) \in \Theta(f+g)$, and by the above remark, we also have $f+g \in \Theta(\max(f,g))$.

Comment: Maybe my confusion is dealing with the `=` sign.  Are we saying that the two sets are equivalent?  This is where I seem to be having trouble.  I understand what you are saying about max<f+g<2max, but I don't see how this proves that the two sets are equal.

Comment: Well, I am sure that you can formalize it, but usually the notation is used very loosely. When one writes $f \in \Theta(g)$, it means for $n$ sufficiently large, there are strictly positive constants $\underline{k}, \overline{k}$ such that $\underline{k} g(n) \leq f(n) \leq \overline{k} g(n)$. When you write $\Theta(f) = \Theta(g)$, the interpretation is that $h \in \Theta(f) $ iff $h \in \Theta(g)$. So I suppose you could define $\Theta(g)$ as the set of $f$s satisfying the above inequalities and all would be fine...

Comment: Okay, I think I see where you are coming from.  I am going to try and formally work this out.

Comment: @MrZander: Note that the inequalities above give explicit constants that show the equality of the $\Theta$ expressions.

Comment: Why are we able to make the logical step between $\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq (f+g)(n) \leq 2\max(f(n),g(n))$ and $\Theta(f+g)=\Theta(\max(f,g))$?  This is what I can't wrap my mind around.

Comment: @MrZander: I have added an elaboration to the answer; hopefully it addresses your concerns?

Comment: Jesus god. Took me like 30 minutes to understand what was going on here

Comment: @Shammy: Thanks :-). Your comment produced a guffaw on this end...

Comment: I'm similarly solving this problem. Is it correct to let say $f(n) + g(n) \le c * $ max$ \{(f(n), g(n)\}$  which $\implies f(n) + g(n) = O($ max $\{f(n), g(n)\}$

Comment: @Shammy: As long as $c \ge 2$.

Comment: So then when $c = 1$ and only when $c = 1$ I can say that $f(n) + g(n) = \Theta($ max $ \{f(n), g(n)\}$ ?

Comment: Augh now I'm confusing my self.

Comment: @Shammy: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Remember that the whole 'O' thing represents a collection of functions, so when we write $h \in \Theta(f+g)$ is means there is some $a,b>0$ and $N>0$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $a(f(n)+g(n)) \le h(n) \le b (f(n)+g(n))$. The above just shows that $\Theta(f+g) = \Theta(\max(f,g))$.

Comment: Oh oh, ok I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Certainly, $\max(f,g) \leq f+g$ so $\max(f,g) = O(f+g)$, and it only remains to establish the lower bound.

If $f = \Theta(g)$, the statement is trivial, so assume $f = O(g)$ and then $2 \max(f,g) = 2g \geq f+g$, which implies $\max(f,g) = \Omega(f+g)$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Just hope this clarifies a bit more:

You want to show that $h(x)=\max(f(x),g(x))=\Theta(f(x)+g(x))$. Observe two cases:

Case1:

$h(x)=f(x)$, hence $f(x) \geq g(x)$. Then $2 h(x) = 2 f(x) \geq f(x) + g(x)$,

$\Leftrightarrow h(x) \geq \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}$

$\Leftrightarrow h(x) = \Omega(f(x)+g(x))$
This gives the lower bound.

Next, $h(x)=f(x) \leq f(x)+g(x)=O(f(x)+g(x))$

Hence, $h(x)=\Theta(f(x)+g(x))$

Case 2:

$h(x)=g(x)$. Similar to Case 1.

Comment: I want to show $\Theta(\max(f(x),g(x)))=\Theta(f(x)+g(x))$