# Suppose $f_1 \in \Theta(g_1) \land f_2 \in \Theta(g_2)$. Prove $f_1 + f_2 \in \Theta(\max\{g_1, g_2\})$.

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I need to prove that

> $f_1 \in \Theta(g_1) \land f_2 \in \Theta(g_2) \implies f_1 + f_2 \in \Theta(\max\{g_1, g_2\})$

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291465/formally-prove-that-theta-maxf-g-thetafg) is relevant, but I have a slightly different case, so I don't know how to translate it into this one, because I need to turn the $f$'s into $g$'s.

Am I allowed to say $\max\{f_1, f_2\} \in \Theta(\max\{g_1, g_2\})$?

Or even $\Theta(\max\{f_1, f_2\}) = \Theta(\max\{g_1, g_2\})$?

Answer (score 3):

Just notice that if 
$$
   c_i \le \frac{f_i}{g_i} \le C_i
$$
then ($n=2$ is the number of functions you are considering)
$$
  \frac{\max f_i}{\max g_j} \le \frac{\sum f_i}{\max g_j} = \sum_i \frac{f_i}{\max_j g_j} \le \sum \frac {f_i}{g_i}\le \sum C_i
$$
and
$$
  \frac{\sum f_i}{\max g_j} = \sum_i \frac{f_i}{\max_j g_j} = \sum_i \min_j \frac{f_i}{g_j} \ge \sum_i \min_j \frac{f_j}{g_j} = n \min c_j
$$

Comment: For the bottom part, if I try to expand the summations, should I get: $\frac{f_1 + f_2}{\max\{g_1,g_2\}} = \min\{\frac{f_1}{g_1},\frac{f_1}{g_2},\frac{f_2}{g_1},\frac{f_2}{g_2}\} \ge \min\{\frac{f_1}{g_1},\frac{f_2}{g_2}\}$?

Comment: I have modified the bottom part, it was wrong.