# Big-Theta sum rule proof

Tags: logic, algorithms, computer-science, theta-functions

> I have four functions $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose that $f_1\in\Theta(g_1)$ and $f_2\in\Theta(g_2)$. I need to prove that $f_1+f_2\in\Theta(\text{max}\{g_1,g_2\})$.

This is fairly easy to see with a specific example such as the following:

Let $f_1=x+5$. Then $f_1\in\Theta(x)$.

Let $f_2=2x^2$. Then $f_2\in\Theta(x^2)$.

$f_1+f_2 = (2x^2)+(x+5)$ which  is $\in\Theta(x^2)$ and $x^2$ is the max of $x$ and $x^2$.

I cannot figure out how to write this as a general proof.

I can say that $f_1+f_2\in O(\text{max}\{g_1,g_2\})$ since I want a bigger value of $g$.

I am having trouble saying that $f_1+f_2\in\Omega(\text{max}\{g_1,g_2\})$ since I don't necessarily know that with a bigger value of g the inequality of $\Omega$ will still apply.

Comment: Someone wrote a nice explanation in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582889/suppose-f-1-in-thetag-1-land-f-2-in-thetag-2-prove-f-1-f-2-in?rq=1